# Grounding a 2 gang metal box in a wet area

Tags: grounding

In my pool area, I have a metal box that has 2 switches (spa air and pool light). Each switch has a green screw and the box itself has 2 green screws. There is also ground coming into the box. How are the grounding connections to be made. The box is suitable for wet locations. No connections have been made yet. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just so I am clear, the second box green screw will not be used?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it's a wet location doesn't make a difference to how you make your wire connections (although it needs to be on a GFCI circuit because it's for a pool light). Connect a pig-tail ground wire the green screw on each of the switches and a 3rd one to the green screw on the box.  Wire nut all three of them together with the ground coming into the box.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just so I am clear, the second box green screw will not be used?

Comment: @GGM - Nope.  My guess is that the box has 2 screws for convenience in choosing which one to use.